# handling mouse events in runtime created objects in c#

Tags: c#, windows, onmousedown

I'm writing a c# windows app, and as one task, I am creating Panel objects at runtime.  I have my custom Panel which is defined as:

```
class FlowState : Panel
{
:
:
}
```

I have an init method to set size, location, etc.  However once this panel is created on the windows form, I want to handle mouse events, such as mouseDown and mouseUp.  If you created a panel at design time and used the gui to define these events, you would get methods like the following (for a panel named 'panel1'):

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

How do I put code into my FlowState object which extends Panel to handle mouse events such as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can attach the event like this...

```
private void CreatePanel()
}
    var panel = new FlowState();
    panel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MouseDown);
}

private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
}
```

Comment: the only comment I would make is that the event is MouseDown and the compiler didn't like the private method also being named MouseDown.  I made it onMouseDown and everything was fine.

Comment: In fact, if you had done this at design time, you would see that same line of code (panel.MouseDown +=...) in FlowState.Designer.cs.  We can dynamically bind the same methods that the GUI would have done.